# Jquery code for checkbox Enable Disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

Hi I want to convert the javascript function code to jquery. can anyone help with this ? Below is my javascript function with HTML code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function enableTextBox() {
        if (document.getElementById("chkCropLoan").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("txtAmount").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("txtAmount").disabled = true;
        if (document.getElementById("chkInvestmentLoan").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("txtInvestmentLoan").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("txtInvestmentLoan").disabled = true;

        if (document.getElementById("chkWarehouseReceipt").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("txtWarehouseReceipt").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("txtWarehouseReceipt").disabled = true;

        if (document.getElementById("chkFarmerProd").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("txtFarmerProd").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("txtFarmerProd").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

HTML code starts here for checkbox and textbox

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Crop Loan</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCropLoan" runat="server" CssClass="check" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="5" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <%-- <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtAmount_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAmount" WatermarkText="Enter Crop loan Amount"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>--%>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgfldvalidator" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the numbers only" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Investment Loan</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInvestmentLoan" runat="server" CssClass="check" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvestmentLoan" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="5" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <%--<cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtInvestmentLoan_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtInvestmentLoan" WatermarkText="Enter Investment loan Amount"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>--%>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtInvestmentLoan" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the numbers only" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Warehouse Receipt Finance</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWarehouseReceipt" runat="server" CssClass="check" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWarehouseReceipt" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="5" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <%--<cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtWarehouseReceipt_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtWarehouseReceipt" WatermarkText="Enter Warehouse Receipt Finance Amount"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>--%>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" ControlToValidate="txtWarehouseReceipt" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the numbers only" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Farmer Producer Companies</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFarmerProd" runat="server" CssClass="check" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFarmerProd" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="5" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <%--<cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender11" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFarmerProd" WatermarkText="Enter Farmer Producer Amount"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>--%>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" ControlToValidate="txtFarmerProd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the numbers only" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure. Just post what you have tried, and what you're having problems with.

Comment: Why you want to do that? Vanilla JS is much faster.

Comment: Before I post an answer, does the current code work?

Comment: always use jQuery's `prop('checked')` for getting and setting checkbox `checked` state. Nothing else seems to work everywhere :)

Comment: I have written the code, but this javascript functionality is not working in IE 8, need Jquery code or other way so that It can work

Comment: When you run the page in a browser and view source, are the id's for these elements long and complicated, or are they simple like 'txtAmount' ? Knowing this will help.

Comment: @MikeN: they are simple like 'txtAmount'..

Comment: Ok, then did King King's answer work?

Comment: @MikeN: No king King ansmwers did not work

Comment: hmmm, try adding a console.log in the function and make sure its getting called when it should be

Comment: @Mike N: ohhk, I haven't used the console.log property still. but will try for that. If u have any reference for that. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: anywhere in your method just put 'Console.log("enableTextBox function has been fired");',  then when you open up developer tools of a web browser (usually done with the F12 key) there will be a console that displays anything written to the console. So keep the tools open and refresh the page. If you see the results in the console it means that the function did in fact execute. If you do not see the log, then the function never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are using master page you may need to change ID in following code

```
function enableTextBox() {

    if ($("#chkCropLoan").prop("checked") == true)
        $("#txtAmount").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("#txtAmount").prop("disabled", true);

    if ($("#chkInvestmentLoan").prop("checked") == true)
        $("#txtInvestmentLoan").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("#txtInvestmentLoan").prop("disabled", true);

    if ($("#chkWarehouseReceipt").prop("checked") == true)
        $("#txtWarehouseReceipt").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("#txtWarehouseReceipt").prop("disabled", true);

    if ($("#chkFarmerProd").prop("checked") == true)
        $("#txtFarmerProd").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("#txtFarmerProd").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: the code is not executing in IE8.:( any thing else ?